# Как решить проблему с кириллицей в JSON?

Tags: json, javascript

Существует проект страницы, на которой пользователь:
1. Выбирает город, отображая план мероприятия.
2. Выбирает время события в мероприятии, отображая описание отдельного события.

Во 2 пункте используется формула:

```
...
newContent += times[loc][i].title.replace(/ /g, '-') + '">';
..
```

которая подгружает описание события по идентификатору, получаемому из элемента title JSON-файла с названиями событий мероприятия (здесь: 3D-моделирование):

```
{
    "CA": [
        {
            "time": "9:00",
            "title": "3D-моделирование"
        },
...
```

ищет соответствующий идентификатор (т.е. `<code>3D-моделирование</code>`) в html-файле и выводит описание на странице (в данном случае не работает, так как идентификатор на латинице - `Intro-to-3D-Modeling`):

```
...
<div id="Intro-to-3D-Modeling">
      <h3>3D-моделирование</h3>
      <p>Описание</p>
    </div>
...
```

Проблема в том, что если в JSON-файле текст в элементах title указан кириллицей, описания не отображаются. Если латиницей - все работает. JSON латиницей не могу написать, так как этот же текст отображается на веб-странице. Естественно, и значения атрибутов id не могу кириллицей написать.
Как быть?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо полного названия использовать некий ID, ну например посчитать MD5 от кириллического названия.

Comment: А как это реализовать? Туплю

Comment: а каким образом вы получаете информацию из файла JSON? Кириллические тексты через [getJSON()][1] прекрасно добавляются на страницу

[1]: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getJSON/

Comment: а какая кодировка используется в json-файле и в html?

Comment: В HTMl явно указана utf-8 и файл сохранен в utf-8
json сохранен в utf-8, явно не указана

Проблема в том, что в JSON значения title указаны на русском
Формула берет значения title и ищет такие же id в файле описаний.
Так как title на русском, то и id она на русском ищет. Здесь и проблема, так как id на англ

Comment: Тогда могу предложить транслитерацию или id писать на русском

Comment: Так вот с русскими id пример не работал. Оказалось - только в Файрфоксе, в остальных работает.
Спасибо, вопрос решен

Comment: Запостите баг команде Файрфокса если в последней версии не работает.
Пишут, что в HTML5 можно любые символы, кроме пробелов, использовать, а в предыдущих версиях только как в идентификаторах переменных. Так что проверьте, какая версия HTML указана у вашей страницы.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 1):

Укажите кодировку для отдаваемого JSON в HTTP-заголовке:

```
Content-Type: application/json, charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score -1):

Одним из вариантов решения будет использовать [data атрибуты](http://htmlbook.ru/samouchitel-html5/atributy-data) и по ним производить поиск
Например:

```
<div id="Intro-to-3D-Modeling" data-title="3D-моделирование">
  <h3>3D-моделирование</h3>
  <p>Описание</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/88207)

Comment: @Denis, спасибо, дополнил